# WordPress wp_enqueue_media() breaks Featured Image

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom WordPress theme and I'm trying to do so without using any plugins whatsoever. I enabled Featured Images for posts by adding the following to my theme's `functions.php`:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array('post'));
```

I added some custom admin settings pages for managing the clients' artwork related files, like icons and logos and whatnot. So, I also added the following to my theme's `functions.php` in order to get the Media Uploader to work on these new settings pages:

```
wp_enqueue_style('media-editor');
wp_enqueue_media();
```

Unfortunately, for some reason, the `wp_enqueue_media();` function call is breaking the Featured Image function in my admin's Edit Post page.

I am able to open the Media Browser, upload an image and select it, but clicking the Set Featured Image does nothing and throws no console errors.

Commenting out `wp_enqueue_media()` fixes the Featured Image, but breaks the custom admin settings page.

The enqueue_media call was performed during the `after_setup_theme` action. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Is there a way to detect which custom admin page I am one, so I can only enable the media uploader on it?

*WordPress Version 4.2.4*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, this will `enqueue media` when you are on custom page.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function( $hook )
    {
        /** @var \WP_Screen $screen */
        $screen = get_current_screen();

       //echo '<pre>';print_r($screen);echo '</pre>';

        if ( 'your_custom_page.php' == $screen->base ) {
            wp_enqueue_media();
        } else return;
    } );
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. There's so many freaking hooks!